# Is it possible to to declare variables within a condition?

Tags: java

This is how I would do a while loop:

```
boolean more = true;
while (more)
{
  // do something
  if (someTest()) 
  {
    more = false;
  }
}
```

That's pretty standard. I'm curious to know if there's a way of doing something similar to the code below in Java: (I think I've seen something like it in C)

```
// The code below doesn't compile (obviously)
while (boolean more = true)
{
  // do something
  if (someTest())
  {
    more = false;
  }
}
```

I only ask this because currently I don't like the way I'm defining the variable used in the condition (in this case: "more") *outside* the scope of the loop, even though it's only relevant *inside* the loop. There's no point it being left hanging around after the loop has finished.

---

*** * Update * ***

An idea came to me following a visit to the Porcaline Chamber of Secrets:

```
for (boolean more=true; more; more=someTest())
{
  // do something
}
```

It's not perfect; It's abusing the for loop and I can't think of a way to execute the loop *at least once*, but it's close... Is there a way to make sure the loop is performed 1+ times?

Comment: for (boolean more=true; more; more=someTest()) ... will always execute at least once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer your question literally, you can do

```
for(boolean more = true; more; ) {
   more = !someTest();
}
```

but this is much the same as

```
while(!someTest());
```

If it must execute at least once you can do

```
do {

} while(!someTest());
```

Comment: `for (var ; cond; )` trick is useful in dealing with iterators: `for (Iterator<?> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) { /* do stuff */ }`. In fact it's recommended in *Effective Java Item 45: Minimize the scope of local variables*

Comment: Your answer popped up just as I submitted my update. Thanks! ... It was probably a bad idea on my part abstracting the condition as a method - the loop only had three lines in it and one of them was setting "more" so encapsulating it in a method would be overkill. I thought it would make the question more concise, but instead left it open to misinterpretation. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case, you can reduce your code to this:

```
while (true) {
  if (someTest()) {
    break;
  }
}
```

In general, you could replace your outer-scope declaration with an inner-scope one, but you'd need to move the loop condition:

```
while (true) {
  boolean more=true;
  ...
  if (someTest()) {
    more = false;
  }
  ...
  if (!more) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Or even:

```
do {
  boolean more=true;
  ...
  if (someTest()) {
    more = false;
  }
  ...
  if (!more) {
    break;
  }
} while (true);
```

I'd opine that defining your condition outside the loop is clearer.

Comment: to be honest, I'm not a big fan of using `while(true) {...}` it seems like a bit of a cop-out. Plus I still have nightmares of debugging other people's spaghetti code littered with huge blocks of `if(false) {...}` [shudder]

Answer (score 0):

KidTempo, in the example you gave, I think that more would be re-initialized each time through the loop. Each time through the loop, the conditional is re-evaluated, so assuming that you are able to define a variable in a conditional, the variable would be re-initialized each time that conditional is re-evaluated. This would also apply to other types of conditionals, so I would say to avoid defining variables in a conditional.